# Where can I see the approval rating of my companions?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm pretty much constantly seeing notifications like "Solas approves" or "Cassandra disapproves", but I still have no idea on how much my companions approve or disapprove of myself in general. I assume those individual actions are accumulated into an overall rating, but I couldn't find anything in the game that indicates how a particular companion feels towards myself.

Is there any way to see how my companions regard myself and if they approve or disapprove of me in general?

Comment: Can't confirm, but I think that feature (so far) has been removed from this one.

Answer (score 9):

As your companions begin to approve of your decisions the outside of the tarot card turns from black to white. If you're romancing a NPC and you go on a personal quest, after completion the face of the card will change based on the decisions in the quest. I've found it difficult to gain full approval from all companions in one playthrough. It's not the same as DA2 due to the fact that if you get full approval from one character and no longer appears on the screen "Iron Bull Approves" if you choose something he disapproves his approval will go down again and not stay at full approval.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know and as far as I could find roaming various forums, you can't.

It seems that Bioware wanted more "instinctive" relationships, where you judge how much people like you based on how they interact with you rather than based on a number. That would also explain why the approval/disapproval notifications are qualified, not quantified like they were in the two previous games.

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure the character tarot cards change based on their approval of your MC. Romancing Cassandra changed hers. while i have been very displeasing to cole and his has now changed to some red bloody looking art work. Cannot say for certain this is the gauge people are looking for, but they do change after specific dialog and actions.

Answer (score 0):

The changing tarot cards definitely have some meaning.

As I've begun to romance Sera her card has changed significantly. Also, following a very personal quest involving Dorian, his picture changed as well.

I believe that each character has at least three cards, one default, one that indicates a deepening friendship, and another that suggests disapproval/increased hostility.

For me, so far only Sera, Dorian, and Blackwall have changed from their default, all three because I spent time improving my relationships with them and doing at least one personal quest/favor for each. I try to keep everyone happy by speaking to them individually and telling them what they want to hear, but major plot decisions inevitably sway some followers in one direction or another. So far cole is the most disapproving, I think because his omniscient nature causes his opinion to change even when he is not in my party.